# How to extract data from tag named section

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract some datas (odds) from an [html page](https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/sports/1/).

The data are included in the tag `<section class="event-list">` which represent a table.

My problem is when I try to extract this tag I have `None` as answer whereas I would like to get all the data include in this tag named `<section>`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#Import htlm from winamax for soccer
winamax_soccer_datas = requests.get('https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/sports/1/')  

contenu_winamax_soccer_datas = BeautifulSoup(winamax_soccer_datas.content, 'lxml')  
title = contenu_winamax_soccer_datas.title
print(title); print("\n")

winamax_soccer_odds = contenu_winamax_soccer_datas.find('section', attrs={'class': "event-list"})
print(winamax_soccer_odds)
```

Comment: the section event list is asynchronously loaded, so you wont be able to extract data from the tag using this method, either save the webpage before running the program or use advanced scrapers like phantomjs for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

you know, the content inside a web page generate **static** or/and **dynamic**. when you use **View Page Source** option in your web browser like chrome, you just get **original HTML used to create the page** and not **Table Content** which generated dynamic. 

when you use `request.get()`, you get static HTML content and your `<section class="event-list">` generated dynamic so there is `None` at the result.


i hope it could helped you :)

Comment: https://blog.cyberwhale.tech/2017/02/01/how-to-parse-dynamic-html-content-using-python/

Answer (score 0):

Do you know PHP? If yes, you can use this package to import your code to DOM, then extract your data https://github.com/samacs/simple_html_dom

Example with your case:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$data = '<section class="event-list">';
$html = str_get_html($data);    
foreach($html->find('section') as $e){
    $classname = $e->class;
}
```